# How to animate a marker through an ArrayList of LatLng points?

Tags: android, arraylist, location, google-maps-api-2, marker

I am using Google Maps API V2 to get the location of the current user and am recording his route by using the onLocationChanged listener. While the user records their route I save all the LatLngs detected at each location change in an arraylist. When the user stops recording their route I place a marker at the first point in the arraylist. My problem now is that I wish to animate the marker through all the points in the arraylist. Can someone please tell me how can I do this?

Things to note is that the array doesn't need sorting because I record the points as they come. I have tried using a for loop to cycle through the array and send the values over but I get an error from the

> final LatLng startLatLng = proj.fromScreenLocation(startPoint);

saying "Unknown Source" along with a NullPointer exception.

Here is my code:

```
case R.id.action_replay:

            int o;

            for(o=0; o<oldlocPoints.size(); ++o){

                if(--o > 1){lastPos = oldlocPoints.get(--o);}
                toPos = oldlocPoints.get(++o);

                animateMarker(markerStart, lastPos, toPos);
            }
 return true;
```

And this is How I try to animate through the markers. The main difficulty I am encountering is that in run() it only seems to want Final type values so I have no idea how to please it.

```
    //Animates marker through the locations saved from the recorded route
public void animateMarker(final Marker marker, LatLng lastPos, final LatLng toPos) {
    final long duration = 1600;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    this.lastPos = lastPos;
    this.toPos = toPos;
    final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    final int o;

    Projection proj = map.getProjection();
    Point startPoint = proj.toScreenLocation(lastPos);
    final LatLng startLatLng = proj.fromScreenLocation(startPoint);

    Log.d(TAG, "" + lastPos + "" + toPos);

    final Interpolator interpolator = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
            float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed / duration);
            double lng = t * toPos.longitude + (1 - t) * startLatLng.longitude;
            double lat = t * toPos.latitude + (1 - t) * startLatLng.latitude;
            markerStart.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lng));
            //markerStart.setPosition(interpolator.interpolate(t, target, replayEnd));
            if (t < 1.0) {
                //Post again 16ms later == 60 frames per second
                handler.postDelayed(this, 32);
            } else {
                //Animation ended
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Can someone please help me?

**UPDATE**
My closest attempt to date is this:

```
while (i<oldlocPoints.size()){


                final long duration = 32;
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                Projection proj = map.getProjection();
                final LatLng toPos = oldlocPoints.get(i/3);

                Point startPoint = proj.toScreenLocation(oldlocPoints.get(i));
                final LatLng startLatLng = proj.fromScreenLocation(startPoint);

                final Interpolator interpolator = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                        float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed / duration);
                        double lng = t * toPos.longitude + (1 - t) * startLatLng.longitude;
                        double lat = t * toPos.latitude + (1 - t) * startLatLng.latitude;
                        markerStart.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lng));
                        //markerStart.setPosition(interpolator.interpolate(t, target, replayEnd));
                        if (t < 1.0) {
                            //Post again 16ms later == 60 frames per second
                            handler.postDelayed(this, 32);
                        } else {
                            //Animation ended
                        }
                    }
                });

                i++;
            }
```

Comment: FWIW, here is a sample app where I animate markers between positions: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Animator

Comment: In addition to CommonsWare's example, which is likely good considering it is CommonsWare, you will probably want to take a look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro in the tab on the left it has Drawing on the Map where it has help with markers, and Changing the View which will help you make sure your view stays centered.

Comment: @zgc7009 I did have a look at those before and they make sense up to the point where they say 'newPosition.setPosition(latLngInterpolator.interpolate(v, startPos, endPos));' where I have no idea what latLngInterpolator is or where it is coming from. I did try implementing it in my code but when I saw that that isn't an import I figured it's some class I don't have.

Comment: @CommonsWare your code goes a bit over my head I'm afraid, I'm not an android expert :(. I don't get the property variable and the LatLngEvaluator. Can you please help me understand them?

Comment: Well, what you're asking for is a bit complicated for a StackOverflow question -- it's a few pages in [a book](http://commonsware.com/Android). The technique comes from [this DevBytes YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WKfZsCKSXVQ), which will review the `LatLngEvaluator` and such.

Comment: Ty. Seems so stupid that I can't move a marker from one location to another and then another and another etc. in a systematical fashion without loads of code. I think I will stick with my best attempt to date which I will update my question with in a minute. It uses the same technique as Google devs suggested but I'm enclosing it in a loop and apart from the marker spazzing out between locations instead of animating it seems like it just needs adjusting...If you could please have a look at it and tell me how I can improve it.

Comment: CommonsWare's solution does not move a marker across many points, it moves it across 2 points which is already easy to do and explained in the Dev Bytes and not needed by any real solution in the real world!

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I am also attempting to move a marker through several LatLng.

Answer (score 8):

try this code :: 
first the MarkerAnimation class :

```
public class MarkerAnimation {
    static GoogleMap map;
    ArrayList<LatLng> _trips = new ArrayList<>() ;
    Marker _marker;
    LatLngInterpolator _latLngInterpolator = new LatLngInterpolator.Spherical();

public void animateLine(ArrayList<LatLng> Trips,GoogleMap map,Marker marker,Context current){
    _trips.addAll(Trips);
    _marker = marker;

    animateMarker();
}


        public void animateMarker() {
            TypeEvaluator<LatLng> typeEvaluator = new TypeEvaluator<LatLng>() {
                @Override
                public LatLng evaluate(float fraction, LatLng startValue, LatLng endValue) {
                    return _latLngInterpolator.interpolate(fraction, startValue, endValue);
                }
            };
            Property<Marker, LatLng> property = Property.of(Marker.class, LatLng.class, "position");

            ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(_marker, property, typeEvaluator, _trips.get(0));

            //ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.o(view, "alpha", 0.0f);
            animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                    //  animDrawable.stop();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                    //  animDrawable.stop();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                    //  animDrawable.stop();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    //  animDrawable.stop();
                    if (_trips.size() > 1) {
                        _trips.remove(0);
                        animateMarker();
                    }
                }
            });

            animator.setDuration(300);
            animator.start();
        }
```

and the _latLngInterpolator which is pre-written for you by google developers  :

```
public interface LatLngInterpolator {
    public LatLng interpolate(float fraction, LatLng a, LatLng b);

    public class Spherical implements LatLngInterpolator {
        @Override
        public LatLng interpolate(float fraction, LatLng from, LatLng to) {
            // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp
            double fromLat = toRadians(from.latitude);
            double fromLng = toRadians(from.longitude);
            double toLat = toRadians(to.latitude);
            double toLng = toRadians(to.longitude);
            double cosFromLat = cos(fromLat);
            double cosToLat = cos(toLat);

            // Computes Spherical interpolation coefficients.
            double angle = computeAngleBetween(fromLat, fromLng, toLat, toLng);
            double sinAngle = sin(angle);
            if (sinAngle < 1E-6) {
                return from;
            }
            double a = sin((1 - fraction) * angle) / sinAngle;
            double b = sin(fraction * angle) / sinAngle;

            // Converts from polar to vector and interpolate.
            double x = a * cosFromLat * cos(fromLng) + b * cosToLat * cos(toLng);
            double y = a * cosFromLat * sin(fromLng) + b * cosToLat * sin(toLng);
            double z = a * sin(fromLat) + b * sin(toLat);

            // Converts interpolated vector back to polar.
            double lat = atan2(z, sqrt(x * x + y * y));
            double lng = atan2(y, x);
            return new LatLng(toDegrees(lat), toDegrees(lng));
        }

        private double computeAngleBetween(double fromLat, double fromLng, double toLat, double toLng) {
            // Haversine's formula
            double dLat = fromLat - toLat;
            double dLng = fromLng - toLng;
            return 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin(dLat / 2), 2) +
                    cos(fromLat) * cos(toLat) * pow(sin(dLng / 2), 2)));
        }
    }
}
```

and call it on your map activity as :

```
 MarkerAnimation.animateLine(TripPoints,map,MovingMarker,context);
```