# How to move google map marker smoothly between two location with waypoint in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to move google map marker smoothly like this [example](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_cartrip.htm). Also in my case has some waypoints additional to start and end location. Already I used below code. but it hasn't constant speed at all point.

```
public static void setAnimation(GoogleMap myMap, final List<LatLng> directionPoint, final Bitmap bitmap) {


    Marker marker = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap))
            .position(directionPoint.get(0))
            .flat(true));

    Marker marker1 = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap))
            .position(directionPoint.get(10))
            .flat(true));

    myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(directionPoint.get(0), 10));

    animateMarker(myMap, marker, marker1, directionPoint, false);
}


private static void animateMarker(GoogleMap myMap, final Marker marker, final Marker marker1, final List<LatLng> directionPoint,
                                  final boolean hideMarker) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    Projection proj = myMap.getProjection();
    final long duration = (long) (30000);

    final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        int i = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
            float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed
                    / duration);
            if (i < directionPoint.size()){
                marker.setPosition(directionPoint.get(i));
                marker1.setPosition(directionPoint.get(i+10));
            }
            i++;


            if (t < 1.0) {
                // Post again 16ms later.
                handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
            } else {
                if (hideMarker) {
                    marker.setVisible(false);
                } else {
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Also I need to turn marker according to route between two location.

Comment: what "below" code?

Comment: @pskink, I added the code

Comment: use `ObjectAnimator` / `ValueAnimator` instead of that `handler.post` stuff - it works much better for custom animations

Comment: you can check the answer for [Animate marker through an Array of Latlng points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23203611/how-to-animate-a-marker-through-an-arraylist-of-latlng-points/32985642#32985642)

Comment: @ pskink & Sarah Maher, Thanks for your reply. I already tried as you said. but problem is that method has not constant moving speed at all point. I need to move marker along the route with constant speed at all point.

Comment: no, `ObjectAnimator` / `ValueAnimator` guarantees constant speed no matter when it is called - all what you need is to find the current location based on `getAnimatedFraction()` which has value from 0 to 1

Comment: @ pskink, Please can you provide some example code for me. It will be very  usefully for me.

Comment: use `ValueAnimator#addUpdateListener` and inside `onAnimationUpdate` call `Log.d` with `animation.getAnimatedFraction()` and see the logcat

Comment: @ pskink, Thanks for your reply. I used `ObjectAnimator` instead of `handler.post`. It's work perfectly. but now I need to know how to rotate marker when use `ObjectAnimator` instead of `ValueAnimator`?

Comment: see Sarah Maher comment above

Comment: Already I used code that given by Sarah Maher. It move marker smoothly but never rotate marker according to polyline.